# TColorButton not found

Tags: delphi

One of my companies software projects has been maintained by an external contractor for many years. His services may not be available to us for much longer so I have been tasked with taking a copy of the source code and checking that I can compile it.

I have never used Delphi before. When I open one of the project files, I receive multiple instances the same warning that says:

> Class TColorButton not found. Ignore the error and continue? NOTE:
>   Ignoring the error may cause components to be deleted or property
>   values lost.

I searched the Delphi help files for TColorButton and found that it is a standard component within a library that ships with Delphi. I see that I have that library installed and TColorButton is listed as one of its components.

[image]

The TColorButton component is not available on the components toolbar despite other controls from the same library being there (for instance TColorBox). I have the same issue if I create a new project and yet the library remains shown as selected in the new project.

[image]

I have tried both trail and community edition versions of Delphi 10.2.3 with the same results. I am probably making a noob mistake somewhere. Can anyone tell me what I need to do to use TColorButton?

Comment: What kind of Project have you created? There are several types of projects to choose from

Comment: You are asking the wrong people. Ask the contractor. They know which components they used. You'll likely need to pay them to help transfer this knowledge. Don't try to do it on the cheap. False economy.

Comment: FWIW, if you get a message like that, always select Cancel. The form can not be edited until the problem was fixed, but nothing was removed or lost. Note that there are 2 different component libraries that come with Delphi: FMX (FireMonkey) and VCL (visual Component Library). But `TColorButton` seems to be an FMX control only. Hard to tell why it can't be found.

Comment: There have been various `TColorButton` components around for donkeys years before FMX became available, just google "vcl tcolorbutton" to see.  Like @DavidHeffernan says, you should ask the contactor, because same name <> same cpmponent.

Comment: @NineBerry I had created an SDI Application. After seeing these comments I created a "FireMonkey Metropolis UI Application" and I am able to use TColorButton in that. It doesn't solve my problem but increased my understanding considerably.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have no doubt that you're absolutely right. This is not a situation I would have got myself into by choice. This is verging on disaster management!

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Yes, I'm working on a copy anyway but I've been very careful not to get myself into a mess by making unintended changes.

Comment: @MartynA Thank you for an important clue that gives me new lines of investigation.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your time. I have a better understanding now and thats what I needed to work out what to try next.

Comment: https://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=1100

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The TColorButton you see installed in your Delphi IDE is part of the FireMonkey components (FMX). It will only be available in the components toolbar and in the forms designer for FireMonkey projects / forms.

You do probably have a VCL based project, not a FireMonkey project. The external coder did probably use a VCL based TColorButton component they created themselves or downloaded from the web.

Look in the source code for a unit with a TColorButton class and install it in your Delphi IDE.

If the source code for the TColorButton component is not included in the source code you received you have to ask the external coder where they got it from.

Comment: Zarko Gajic the former host of Delphi.About blog made a cusom colored button component in the past with name TColorButton so it is possible that OP is looking for that component. You can find Zarko's the article with a link to said component here: https://www.thoughtco.com/source-code-for-tcolorbutton-4077901 NOTE: I'm not sure this is the exact component OP is looking for. It is just a hunch.

Comment: Accepted because I have at least been able to verify the project is not an FMX application and that the installed TColorButton does work in a newly created FMX application.